# ESP8266 Scheduler. Tasks in separate files arduino IDE

Tags: scheduled-tasks, scheduler, esp8266, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

I want to create simple weather station with esp8266 but with scheduler to updating data and GUI more simultaneously. I've downloaded scheduler from [here](https://github.com/nrwiersma/ESP8266Scheduler) but there is information:

```
Tasks must be declared globally on the stack (not a pointer). Failure to do so will crash your device
```

Does that mean that I have to write all task classes in *.ino file? Can I save them in separate files and call to sketch file? How to do that? I've tried few times but the code won't compile.
Simpliest example of sketch:

```
#include <Scheduler.h>
#include <Arduino.h>

class SimpleTask : public Task {
protected:
    void setup() {
      Serial.println("Setup func");

    }

    void loop() {
      Serial.println("Loop func");
      delay(600);
    }
   
} simple_task;

void setup() {
      Serial.begin(115200);

Scheduler.start(&simple_task);
Scheduler.begin();
}

void loop() { }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Tasks must be declared globally on the stack (not a pointer).

I think strictly this means that Tasks must not be created on the heap and need to be global, static objects.

This can be done by creating the object in a separate file and declaring the object using the `extern` keyword.

e.g. an example `mysimpletask.h`:

```
#ifndef __MySIMPLETASK_H__
#define __MySIMPLETASK_H__

#include <Scheduler.h>

class MySimpleTask : public Task {
protected:
  void setup();
  void loop();
};

extern MySimpleTask my_simple_task;

#endif
```

The implementation in `mysimpletask.cpp`:

```
#include "mysimpletask.h"

void MySimpleTask::setup() {
  Serial.println("Setup func");
}

void MySimpleTask::loop() {
  Serial.println("Loop func");
  delay(600);
}

MySimpleTask my_simple_task;
```

And the sketch:

```
#include <Scheduler.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "mysimpletask.h"

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  Scheduler.start(&my_simple_task);
  Scheduler.begin();
}

void loop() { }
```